Combinator Expression Parser in Rust
I am writing a parser/evaluator for combinator expressions. My end goal with this project is (attempt to) solve AoC 2024 using only combinatory logic.
I am representing combinator expressions as sequences of items, where each element left-associated is applied to the one after it. An element can either be a single combinator/variable or a subexpression containing another sequence of elements (or a bracket abstraction for eliminating variables).
I am using S K I B C as my combinator basis. The bracket abstraction/variable elimination algorithm I am using is as follows:
Let combinator Zabc...wx=z where z is some combinator expression.
Let Zabc...w=[z]_x where [z]_x is the expression that reduces to z when heading a redux tailed by x

Substitute for [z]_x as using the following rules:
[x]_x = I
[f]_x = K f              iff f does not contain x
[fx]_x = f               iff f does not contain x
[fg]_x = B f [g]_x       iff f does not contain x but g does
[fg]_x = C [f]_x g       iff f does contain x but g does not
[fg]_x = S [f]_x [g]_x   iff both f and g contain x

Repeat for each argument of Z

I am looking for feedback on a couple things:

The most important is speed. If I have any hope of being able to solve an AoC problem, I need this be run much faster. It took around 30s to calculate the 7th fibonacci number when compiling in the debug profile. The release profile was consistently around 10x faster that the debug profile. The release profile took about 20s and >3min. for the 8th and 9th fib number respectively. Needless to say I did not test the debug profile with these numbers. I obviously don't expect crazy performance out of a purely mathematical language, but I think it is obvious that there are some optimizations to be made. I know I have quite a few .clone()s lying around, but afaik they are necessary.
The relationship between my different data types Combinator, Expression, and Element kinda suck. I would like to be able to easily convert between them. I am not sure the best way to do this.
I am not the biggest fan of all the mutability I am using. Would it be more idiomatic for all the functions to mutably consume combinator and then return it?

Any feedback is appreciated.
Here is the repo for reference.
src/parse.rs
use super::{Element, Expression};
use nom::{
    branch::alt,
    character::complete::{alphanumeric1, char, satisfy},
    combinator::{map, recognize},
    multi::{many0, many1},
    sequence::{delimited, terminated, tuple},
    IResult,
};

pub fn expression(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, Vec<Element>> {
    many1(element)(s)
}

fn element(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, Element> {
    alt((exp_item, subexpression, abstraction))(s)
}

fn exp_item(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, Element> {
    map(item, |i| Element::Item(i.to_string()))(s)
}

fn subexpression(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, Element> {
    map(delimited(char('('), expression, char(')')), |e| {
        Element::SubExpression(Expression(e))
    })(s)
}

fn abstraction(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, Element> {
    map(
        tuple((
            delimited(char('['), expression, char(']')),
            nom::sequence::preceded(char('_'), item),
        )),
        |(a, v)| Element::Abstraction(Expression(a), v.to_string()),
    )(s)
}

pub fn declaration(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, (&str, Vec<&str>)> {
    terminated(tuple((item, many0(item))), char('='))(s)
}

fn item(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    alt((alphanumeric_char, curly_brace_delimited))(s)
}

fn alphanumeric_char(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    recognize(satisfy(|c| c.is_alphanumeric()))(s)
}

fn curly_brace_delimited(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    delimited(char('{'), alphanumeric1, char('}'))(s)
}

src/lib.rs
mod parse;

use anyhow::Result;
use nom::combinator::all_consuming;
use parse::{declaration, expression};
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct CombinatorContext(HashSet<Combinator>);

impl CombinatorContext {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self(HashSet::new())
    }

    fn validate(c: &Expression, allowed_symbols: &Vec<String>) -> bool {
        c.0.iter().all(|e| match e {
            Element::Item(i) => allowed_symbols.contains(i),
            Element::SubExpression(s) => CombinatorContext::validate(s, allowed_symbols),
            Element::Abstraction(..) => false,
        })
    }

    fn register(&mut self, c: Combinator, allowed_symbols: &Vec<String>) -> Result<Combinator> {
        if !Self::validate(&c.expression, allowed_symbols) {
            anyhow::bail!("Unable to register");
        }
        self.0.insert(c.clone());

        Ok(c)
    }

    pub fn register_strict(&mut self, c: Combinator) -> Result<Combinator> {
        Self::register(
            self,
            c,
            &vec!["S", "K", "I"].iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect(),
        )
    }

    pub fn register_loose(&mut self, c: Combinator) -> Result<Combinator> {
        Self::register(
            self,
            c,
            &vec!["S", "K", "I", "B", "C"]
                .iter()
                .map(|s| s.to_string())
                .collect(),
        )
    }
}

pub trait AbstractionElimination {
    fn contains(&self, variable: &Element) -> bool;
    fn contains_abstraction(&self) -> bool;
    fn abstraction_substitution(&mut self) -> &mut Self;
    fn reduce_parens(&mut self) -> &mut Self;
    fn reduce_expression(&mut self) -> &mut Self;
    fn context_substitution(&mut self, context: &CombinatorContext) -> &mut Self;
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Hash)]
pub struct Combinator {
    pub name: String,
    pub args: Vec<String>,
    pub expression: Expression,
}

impl Combinator {
    pub fn parse(s: &str) -> Result<Self> {
        let (rest, (name, args)) = declaration(s).unwrap(); // TODO: Propagate
        let (_, exp) = all_consuming(expression)(rest).unwrap();

        let mut c = Self {
            name: name.to_string(),
            args: args.into_iter().map(|a| a.to_string()).collect(),
            expression: Expression(exp),
        };
        c.reduce_parens();

        Ok(c)
    }

    pub fn add_abstraction(&mut self) -> Option<()> {
        if self.args.len() == 0 {
            return None;
        }
        self.expression = Expression(vec![Element::Abstraction(
            self.expression.clone(),
            self.args.pop()?,
        )]);
        Some(())
    }

    pub fn abstraction_elimination(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        for _ in 0..self.args.len() {
            self.add_abstraction();
            while self.contains_abstraction() {
                self.abstraction_substitution();
                self.reduce_parens();
            }
        }

        self
    }

    pub fn apply(&self, name: &str, mut args: Expression) -> Self {
        assert_eq!(self.args.len(), 0);
        let mut c = self.clone();
        c.name = name.to_string();
        c.expression.0.append(&mut args.0);
        c.reduce_expression();
        c
    }
}

impl AbstractionElimination for Combinator {
    fn contains(&self, variable: &Element) -> bool {
        self.expression.contains(variable)
    }

    fn contains_abstraction(&self) -> bool {
        self.expression.contains_abstraction()
    }

    fn abstraction_substitution(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        self.expression.abstraction_substitution();
        self
    }

    fn reduce_parens(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        self.expression.reduce_parens();
        self
    }

    fn reduce_expression(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        self.expression.reduce_expression();
        self
    }

    fn context_substitution(&mut self, context: &CombinatorContext) -> &mut Self {
        self.expression.context_substitution(context);
        self
    }
}

impl std::fmt::Display for Combinator {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} ", self.name)?;
        for arg in self.args.iter() {
            write!(f, "{arg} ")?;
        }
        write! {f, "= {}", self.expression}
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Hash)]
pub struct Expression(Vec<Element>);

impl Expression {
    pub fn parse(s: &str) -> Result<Self> {
        let (_, elements) = all_consuming(expression)(s).unwrap();
        Ok(Self(elements))
    }

    pub fn apply(&self, mut args: Expression) -> Self {
        let mut c = self.clone();
        c.0.append(&mut args.0);
        // c.reduce_expression();
        c
    }
}

impl AbstractionElimination for Expression {
    fn contains(&self, variable: &Element) -> bool {
        self.0.iter().any(|e| e.contains(variable))
    }

    fn contains_abstraction(&self) -> bool {
        self.0.iter().any(|e| e.contains_abstraction())
    }

    fn abstraction_substitution(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        self.0.iter_mut().for_each(|e| {
            e.abstraction_substitution();
        });
        self
    }

    fn reduce_parens(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        // Remove parens around the first element if it is a subexpression
        match self.0.first().unwrap() {
            Element::Item(_) => {}
            Element::SubExpression(s) => {
                self.0.splice(0..1, s.0.clone());
            }
            Element::Abstraction(_, _) => {}
        };

        // Remove parens around subexpressions with a single element
        self.0.iter_mut().for_each(|e| match e {
            Element::SubExpression(s) => {
                if s.0.len() == 1 {
                    *e = s.0.get(0).unwrap().clone();
                };
            }
            _ => {}
        });

        // Recursively reduce any subexpressions
        self.0.iter_mut().for_each(|e| match e {
            Element::SubExpression(s) => {
                s.reduce_parens();
            }
            Element::Abstraction(s, _) => {
                s.reduce_parens();
            }
            Element::Item(_) => {}
        });
        self
    }

    fn reduce_expression(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        loop {
            self.reduce_parens();
            let mut made_substitution = false;
            if self.0.len() > 0 {
                match &self.0[0] {
                    Element::Item(i) if i == "S" && self.0.len() >= 4 => {
                        let x = self.0.remove(1);
                        let y = self.0.remove(1);
                        let z = self.0.remove(1);
                        self.0.remove(0); // Remove S
                        let yz_subexpr = Element::SubExpression(Expression(vec![y, z.clone()]));
                        self.0.insert(0, x);
                        self.0.insert(1, z);
                        self.0.insert(2, yz_subexpr);
                        made_substitution = true;
                    }
                    Element::Item(i) if i == "K" && self.0.len() >= 3 => {
                        let x = self.0.remove(1);
                        self.0.remove(1);
                        self.0.remove(0);
                        self.0.insert(0, x);
                        made_substitution = true;
                    }
                    Element::Item(i) if i == "I" && self.0.len() >= 2 => {
                        let next_elem = self.0.remove(1);
                        self.0.remove(0);
                        self.0.insert(0, next_elem);
                        made_substitution = true;
                    }
                    Element::Item(i) if i == "B" && self.0.len() >= 4 => {
                        let f = self.0.remove(1);
                        let g = self.0.remove(1);
                        let x = self.0.remove(1);
                        self.0.remove(0);
                        let gx_subexpr = Element::SubExpression(Expression(vec![g, x]));
                        self.0.insert(0, f);
                        self.0.insert(1, gx_subexpr);
                        made_substitution = true;
                    }
                    Element::Item(i) if i == "C" && self.0.len() >= 4 => {
                        let f = self.0.remove(1);
                        let x = self.0.remove(1);
                        let y = self.0.remove(1);
                        self.0.remove(0);
                        self.0.insert(0, f);
                        self.0.insert(1, y);
                        self.0.insert(2, x);
                        made_substitution = true;
                    }
                    _ => {}
                }
            }

            if made_substitution {
                self.reduce_parens();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        self.0.iter_mut().for_each(|e| {
            e.reduce_expression();
        });
        self.reduce_parens();
        self
    }

    fn context_substitution(&mut self, context: &CombinatorContext) -> &mut Self {
        for element in self.0.iter_mut() {
            for d in context.0.iter() {
                match element {
                    Element::Item(i) if *i == d.name => {
                        *element = Element::SubExpression(d.expression.clone());
                    }
                    Element::Item(..) => (),
                    Element::SubExpression(..) => (),
                    Element::Abstraction(..) => panic!(),
                };
            }

            match element {
                Element::SubExpression(s) => {
                    s.context_substitution(context);
                }
                _ => (),
            }
        }
        self.reduce_parens();
        self
    }
}

impl std::fmt::Display for Expression {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        for (idx, element) in self.0.iter().enumerate() {
            if idx != 0 {
                write!(f, " ")?;
            }
            write!(f, "{element}")?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl From<Vec<Element>> for Expression {
    fn from(value: Vec<Element>) -> Self {
        Self(value)
    }
}

impl From<Expression> for Vec<Element> {
    fn from(value: Expression) -> Self {
        value.0
    }
}

// impl From<Vec<&str>> for Expression {
//     fn from(value: Vec<&str>) -> Self {
//         value
//             .into_iter()
//             .map(|s| s.into())
//             .collect::<Vec<Element>>()
//             .into()
//     }
// }

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Hash)]
pub enum Element {
    Item(String),
    SubExpression(Expression),
    Abstraction(Expression, String),
}

impl AbstractionElimination for Element {
    fn contains(&self, variable: &Element) -> bool {
        match self {
            Element::Item(i) => Element::Item(i.to_string()) == *variable,
            Element::SubExpression(s) => s.contains(variable),
            Element::Abstraction(s, _) => s.contains(variable),
        }
    }

    fn contains_abstraction(&self) -> bool {
        match self {
            Element::Item(_) => false,
            Element::SubExpression(s) => s.contains_abstraction(),
            Element::Abstraction(_, _) => true,
        }
    }

    fn abstraction_substitution(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        *self = match self {
            Self::Item(_) => self.clone(),
            Self::SubExpression(s) => {
                s.abstraction_substitution();
                self.clone()
            }
            Self::Abstraction(s, v) => match s.0.as_slice() {
                [f] => match f {
                    Self::Item(i) => match i == v {
                        // [x]_x = I
                        true => Self::Item("I".to_string()),
                        // [f]_x = K f
                        false => Self::SubExpression(Expression(vec![
                            Element::Item("K".to_string()),
                            f.clone(),
                        ])),
                    },
                    _ => panic!(),
                },
                [f @ .., g] => match (
                    f.iter().any(|e| e.contains(&Self::Item(v.to_string()))),
                    g.contains(&Self::Item(v.to_string())),
                    matches!(g, Self::Item(_)),
                ) {
                    (true, true, _) => {
                        // [fg]_x = S [f] [g]
                        Self::SubExpression(Expression(vec![
                            Self::Item("S".to_string()),
                            Self::Abstraction(Expression(f.to_vec()), v.clone()),
                            Self::Abstraction(Expression(vec![g.clone()]), v.clone()),
                        ]))
                    }
                    (true, false, _) => {
                        // [fg]_x = C [f] g
                        Self::SubExpression(Expression(vec![
                            Self::Item("C".to_string()),
                            Self::Abstraction(Expression(f.to_vec()), v.clone()),
                            g.clone(),
                        ]))
                    }
                    (false, true, true) => {
                        // [fx]_x = f
                        Self::SubExpression(Expression(f.to_vec()))
                    }
                    (false, true, false) => {
                        // [fg]_x = B f [g]
                        Self::SubExpression(Expression(vec![
                            Self::Item("B".to_string()),
                            Self::SubExpression(Expression(f.to_vec())),
                            Self::Abstraction(Expression(vec![g.clone()]), v.clone()),
                        ]))
                    }
                    (false, false, _) => {
                        // [f]_x = K f
                        Self::SubExpression(Expression(vec![
                            Self::Item("K".to_string()),
                            Self::SubExpression(Expression(vec![
                                Self::SubExpression(Expression(f.to_vec())),
                                g.clone(),
                            ])),
                        ]))
                    }
                },
                _ => panic!(),
            },
        };

        self
    }

    fn reduce_parens(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        *self = match self {
            Self::Item(_) => self.clone(),
            Self::SubExpression(s) => Self::SubExpression(s.reduce_parens().clone()),
            Self::Abstraction(s, v) => Self::Abstraction(s.reduce_parens().clone(), v.clone()),
        };
        self
    }

    fn reduce_expression(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        match self {
            Self::Item(_) => (),
            Self::SubExpression(s) => {
                s.reduce_expression();
            }
            Self::Abstraction(_, _) => panic!(),
        };
        self
    }

    fn context_substitution(&mut self, context: &CombinatorContext) -> &mut Self {
        context.0.iter().for_each(|d| match self {
            Self::Item(i) if *i == d.name => {
                *self = Self::SubExpression(d.expression.clone());
            }
            Self::Item(..) => (),
            Self::SubExpression(s) => {
                s.context_substitution(context);
            }
            Self::Abstraction(..) => panic!(),
        });
        self
    }
}

impl std::fmt::Display for Element {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::Item(i) => write!(f, "{i}"),
            Self::SubExpression(s) => write!(f, "({s})"),
            Self::Abstraction(s, v) => write!(f, "[{s}]_{v}"),
        }
    }
}

impl From<Vec<Element>> for Element {
    fn from(value: Vec<Element>) -> Self {
        Self::SubExpression(value.into())
    }
}

impl From<&str> for Element {
    fn from(value: &str) -> Self {
        Self::Item(value.to_string())
    }
}

impl From<Vec<&str>> for Element {
    fn from(value: Vec<&str>) -> Self {
        Self::SubExpression(
            value
                .into_iter()
                .map(|s| s.into())
                .collect::<Vec<Element>>()
                .into(),
        )
    }
}

impl From<Expression> for Element {
    fn from(value: Expression) -> Self {
        Self::SubExpression(value)
    }
}

src/main.rs
use anyhow::Result;
use combinator_parser::{AbstractionElimination, Combinator, CombinatorContext, Expression};

fn prelude(context: &mut CombinatorContext) {
    vec![
        "M=SII",
        "Y=BM(CBM)",
        "{True}fg=f",
        "{False}fg=g",
        "{Not}b=b{False}{True}",
        "{Pair}xyb=bxy",
        "{First}p=p{True}",
        "{Second}p=p{False}",
        "{0}=I",
        "{IsZero}={First}",
        "1={Pair}{False}0",
        "{Next}n={Pair}{False}n",
        "{Prev}n={Second}n",
        "{ApplyPrime}anfx={IsZero}nx(f(a({Prev}n)fx))",
        "{Apply}=Y{ApplyPrime}",
        "{Add}nm={Apply}n{Next}m",
        "{Mult}nm={Apply}n({Add}m)0",
        "{NextFibPair}p={Pair}({Second}p)({Add}({First}p)({Second}p))",
        "{Fib}n={First}({Apply}n{NextFibPair}({Pair}01))",
    ]
    .into_iter()
    .for_each(|p| {
        let mut c = Combinator::parse(p).unwrap();
        c.abstraction_elimination().context_substitution(context);
        context.register_loose(c).unwrap();
    });
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut context = CombinatorContext::new();
    prelude(&mut context);

    let mut e = Expression::parse(&num_to_exp(8))?;
    println!("{e}");
    e.context_substitution(&context).reduce_expression();
    println!("{e}");

    Ok(())
}

fn num_to_exp(n: i32) -> String {
    if n == 0 {
        return "{Apply}({Fib}(0))fx".to_string();
    }
    let mut next_expr = "0".to_string();
    for _ in 0..n {
        next_expr = format!("{{Next}}({})", next_expr);
    }
    let fib_expr = format!("{{Fib}}({})", next_expr);
    let apply_expr = format!("{{Apply}}({})fx", fib_expr);
    apply_expr
}

